# Doubt regarding alias

Tags: applescript, alias

I have read in an applescript document that- ‘alias’ is a keyword indicating that, after 
compilation (i.e. checking of the syntax), the script should remember the ID of the file and, upon execution, should not ask the Finder for a file at the location as specified by the defined path, but based on the ID.

So I decided to play with it using this script-

```
set samplePath to alias "Mac:Miraaj:eCBTMood:anim1.png"
tell application "Finder"
    open samplePath
end tell
```

I compiled this script and saved it as an AppleScript application. I executed it by double clicking it and it opened the correct file. Then I changed the name of file to anim2.png, and re-executed the application. I thought it should again open the same file but it gave this error:

> File Mac:Miraaj:eCBTMood:anim1.png was
>   not found

Can anyone suggest me if I have done anything wrong or interpreted 'alias' wrongly?

Thanks,

Miraaj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work if you set up the alias as a property rather than as a simple variable.

I copied your script and duplicated the behavior you noticed: if the file is moved or renamed, the script can’t find it any more.

I then modified the script to be:

```
property samplePath : alias "Mimosa:Users:jerry:Desktop:Lost Cities"
tell application "Finder"
    open samplePath
end tell
```

Now, the script application was able to find the file on moving it. And it was able to find the file when I renamed it.

The difference, I think, is that properties are saved in applications on save and between instances, but simple variables need to be recreated each time from the original path, which won’t work if the original path fails.

Consider this variation:

```
set samplePath to alias "Mimosa:Users:jerry:Desktop:Lost Cities"

on idle
    global samplePath
    tell application "Finder"
        open samplePath
    end tell
    return 30
end idle
```

It’s set up like yours, but the script repeats every thirty seconds (save it as “Stay Open” to get this behavior). If you close the file and then move it, the script will find the file at the next iteration. It will likewise find it if you rename the file.

This is because the script doesn’t have to re-interpret the original file path. It’s using the saved alias, which maintains itself even if the file moves or is renamed.

As soon as it has to go back to your script text, it will fail; even with the “property” variation, the link will be broken if I open up the script in AppleScript Editor again, since it then tries to reinterpret the original, now incorrect, path.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is wrong, or at least poorly worded. Applescript applications aren't going to save that information between runtimes; I don't know of any application that would save that information unless the developer explicitly does so.

If the location is hard coded and the file is in the correct location at the time the script calls for the alias then you can move that alias to any location and it will be fine. At the same time, renaming the file will cause subsequent operations to fail, and that's why I think the docs are poorly worded. In the end, once you quit, all of that information goes away.

I use `alias` all the time in my scripts, but I have never seen it "automagically" manage file locations between runtimes. I always must have files in the exact location as specified in the script.